# How to redirect when Javascript is disabled (like new Twitter layout)

Tags: javascript, ajax, seo

I'm trying to create a full ajax based website. For now i'm just researching how it all works. The best example i think is Twitter. Twitter does something when no javascript is enabled, but i'm unable to find out how. When you disable javascript and go to twitter, '?_twitter_noscript=1' is appended to the url. Any idea how they do this?

kind regards,

Daan

Comment: I don't see that behavior with JS disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twitter uses meta refresh when Javascript is disabled.

I found the following code in source of http://www.twitter.com when Javascript is enabled:

```
<noscript>
        <meta http-equiv=refresh content="0; URL=/?_twitter_noscript=1" />
</noscript>
```

Note: The source of http://twitter.com/?_twitter_noscript=1 will not have this code

Comment: i also found it this morning, the reason why i didn't found it yesterday was so stupid. I forgot you needed to be logged in to use the full ajax twitter UI.

Answer (score 3):

They have a hidden input on their signup form:

```
<input id="redirect_after_login" name="redirect_after_login" type="hidden" value="/?_twitter_noscript=1" />
```

When script is enabled, that changes to:

```
<input id="redirect_after_login" name="redirect_after_login" type="hidden" value="/" />
```

So my assumption is that they have some JavaScript changing the value of that input.

Comment: Yup, and with JS disabled, the `value="/?_twitter_noscript=1"` is submitted to the login script.

Comment: ok, but how does this redirect then, because if it's a hidden input it needs to be submitted or something like that?

Comment: Yes, however they are processing the login form is looking for the value of that input and then acting accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

with me, the Twitter don't work with javascript disabled.
i have success with this code created by me:

in index.php

```
<?php
if (!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();
$url = !isset($_SESSION['ajaxpage']) ? '' : $_SESSION['ajaxpage'];
$_SESSION['ajaxpage'] = '';
if (!isset($_GET['noscript'])) echo '<noscript><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=/'.$url.'?noscript=1" /></noscript>';
?>
```

in each php file i call _head.php that contains:

```
<?php
if(!isset($_GET['ajax'])){
    if (!isset($_GET['noscript'])){
        if (!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();
        $_SESSION['ajaxpage'] = $ajax_page;
        header('Location: /#!/'.$ajax_page);
    } else {
        // normal functions, requires... of all pages
    }
}
?>
```

in each php file i have var with the link to page, like:

```
<?php
$ajax_page = '/contact/'; //change this for each page
include_once('_head.php');
?>
```

so, that's it!
each ajax load, please join '?ajax' to url, like:

```
$("body").delegate("a", "click", function(event){
    var lnk = $(this).attr("href");
    var addAjax = lnk.indexOf('?')>0 ? "&ajax" : "?ajax";
    $("#content").load("/"+lnk+addAjax);
});
```